# Printing multiple pages of smaller format on one page

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, adobe-reader

I know it is easily possible to let the printer drivers shrink your page so that multiple of them fit on one page.

I want to do the same thing, but in a slightly different version. I have a Word document with a very special width and height. Because it's much smaller than DIN A4, I want to print multiple of them on one page. How can I do that whilst keeping the width and height the same?

Answer (score 1):

I've never been able to do this from Word natively but I have used [FinePrint](https://fineprint.com/) which will fit multiple document pages onto one page for printing.

It's a paid for application (it costs $49.95), but there is a [free version](https://fineprint.com/fp/) which does have some limitations and include "Printed by Fine Print" (or something similar) in the footer, but might be OK for you.

Comment: I will report back.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm sure this program can do it, but for me it did scale, too.

Comment: FinePrint changed their website. I haven't tried their free versions - would you mind checking if it still works?

Answer (score 0):

Word can do this natively. In the lower right of the print dialog there is the option to print multiple pages on a single one as well as scaling options (which might come in handy to prevent scaling down the pages even further if they are smaller than A5).

Note: It seems that Word won't scale down the pages as long as they aren't larger than the portion of the tiles page they should occupy.

Comment: Do I have to choose "No scaling" or the output format?

Comment: It appears so, yes.

Comment: Uhm... this was an "either-or" question... ;)
However, this didn't work. For some reason it only printed one copy on the paper - and it also printed a textfield that went over the right border. For some reason, this was also not displayed in the correct color, but I'm sure that is another problem...

Comment: More importantly: what about Adobe Reader?